# AWS S3: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, amazon-s3

I am really pulling my hair off on this one.

I tried to run this command on my EC2 instance:

```
aws s3 cp myapp-layer.zip s3://lambda-layer-myapp/myapp-layer.zip
```

and got the following error:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

I have configure AWS permissions such that:

1. the IAM role that my EC2 instance is using has full S3 access to all resources;
2. the bucket `lambda-layer-myapp` has turn off "Block public access"
3. the bucket policy of the bucket is like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "MyPolicy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowGetPutFrom_EC2-to-S3_role",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123123123:role/EC2-to-S3"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::lambda-layer-myapp/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::lambda-layer-myapp"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

so allowing the IAM role to do any S3 actions on the bucket.

But I still get this error.

What does it want?

---

As the comments suggested, I am probably not using the IAM Role that I think I am using. After I tried the `aws sts get-caller-identity` command, I have an interesting observation:

In my local computer which I have configured AWS before, I can successfully execute this command:

```
aws s3 cp myapp-layer.zip s3://lambda-layer-myapp/myapp-layer.zip
```

and `aws sts get-caller-identity` gives

```
{
    "UserId": "123456789qweasd",
    "Account": "123123",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::123123:user/my-user"
}
```

This role has the admin permissions though.
It can do all things on all resources

However, in the EC2 instance, `aws sts get-caller-identity` gives the exact same result as in my local computer, but the `aws s3 cp` command gives the `AccessDenied` error instead.

Now it is even more confused.

I connected my visual studio code 2 to my EC2 instance.
It fails to load S3 buckets in the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio Code:

```
2023-04-18 07:29:18 [ERROR]: AccessDenied: Access Denied
    at constructor.extractError (/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.68.0/dist/src/main.js:27:10373)
    at constructor.callListeners (/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.68.0/dist/src/main.js:24:21199)
    at constructor.emit (/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.68.0/dist/src/main.js:24:20908)
    at constructor.emitEvent (/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.68.0/dist/src/main.js:24:6757)
    at constructor.e (/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.68.0/dist/src/main.js:24:2343)
    at U.runTo (/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.68.0/dist/src/main.js:38:1767)
    at /home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.68.0/dist/src/main.js:38:1979
    at constructor.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.68.0/dist/src/main.js:24:2554)
    at constructor.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.68.0/dist/src/main.js:24:6812)
    at constructor.callListeners (/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.68.0/dist/src/main.js:24:21303)
    at constructor.emit (/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.68.0/dist/src/main.js:24:20908)
    at constructor.emitEvent (/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.68.0/dist/src/main.js:24:6757)
    at constructor.e (/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.68.0/dist/src/main.js:24:2343)
    at U.runTo (/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.68.0/dist/src/main.js:38:1767)
    at /home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.68.0/dist/src/main.js:38:1979
    at constructor.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.68.0/dist/src/main.js:24:2554)
    at constructor.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.68.0/dist/src/main.js:24:6812)
    at constructor.callListeners (/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.68.0/dist/src/main.js:24:21303)
    at e (/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.68.0/dist/src/main.js:24:21084)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server/extensions/amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.68.0/dist/src/main.js:19:41698)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:538:35)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  code: 'AccessDenied',
  region: null,
  time: 2023-04-18T07:29:18.657Z,
  requestId: '123123123',
  extendedRequestId: '123123123+1cwbI11rRes+h8=',
  cfId: undefined,
  statusCode: 403,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 33.43262734821166
}
```

Comment: What does `aws sts get-caller-identity` show?

Comment: It would appear that either the IAM Role does not have sufficient permissions, or the AWS CLI is not using the IAM Role that you think it is using. FYI, there is no need for the Bucket Policy -- granting access via the IAM Role is sufficient. But the fact that the Bucket Policy is not granting access is another hint that you're probably not using the IAM Role that you think you are using! As per @luk2302's suggestion, start by running `aws sts get-caller-identity` to find out what credentials are being used.

Comment: @luk2302  Thank you for the reply. Please see my updated post. I am indeed not using the `EC2-to-S3` role to access the S3 bucket. However, in my local computer using the same IAM role would work, but in EC2 it fails

Comment: @JohnRotenstein  Thank you for the reply. Please see my updated post. I am indeed not using the `EC2-to-S3` role to access the S3 bucket. However, in my local computer using the same IAM role would work, but in EC2 it fails

Comment: How are you assuming the IAM Role on your local computer before using the AWS CLI? Normally the AWS CLI uses an IAM User, not an IAM Role. Therefore, it seems strange that `get-caller-identity` would be "exact same result" on your computer and the EC2 instance.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have done `aws configure` in the EC2 instance terminal and configured the same aws credentials as my local computer. I used Visual Studio Code to connect into the EC2 instance which is the development workstation and I used AWS Toolkit in VS code to connect to AWS console.

Comment: I am quite confused! How did you provide credentials for the IAM Role using `aws configure`? It only accepts an Access Key and a Secret Key, which would belong to an IAM User, not an IAM Role (unless you called AssumeRole() and obtained temporary credentials). Similarly, you should not be entering any credentials on the EC2 instance -- you should be assigning the IAM Role to the instance in the EC2 Management Console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253208/discussion-between-kid-learning-c-and-john-rotenstein).

Answer (score 1):

Based on what @John Rotenstein has discussed with me, I was finally able to find the reason.

Here is what I did one day earlier to when I got stuck with the above issue:

1. I needed to deploy an AWS Lambda function with access to an EFS file system in my VPC. Therefore I had to deployed the AWS Lambda function with VPC configuration.
2. This Lambda function is supposed to download files from S3 bucket into the EFS file system, do some work and upload files from EFS back to S3 bucket. In order for the Lambda function in the VPC to access S3 bucket, I had to add a VPC Endpoint for S3 in my VPC dashboard.
3. I configure the permission policy of the VPC Endpoint as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy123123123",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt123123123",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::myTestBucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::myTestBucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and `myTestBucket` is the bucket that contains the files needed to be downloaded, processed and re-uploaded again.

Therefore, I have created a situation where everything in my VPC can only perform 3 types of actions on that bucket only.

As soon as I configured the VPC Endpoint to allowed full access:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Everything worked just fine.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out! Its behaviour was certainly confusing!